# Repeated measure missing main effect

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, jasp

I have conducted a repated measures ANOVA with a 3 (scenario) x 2 (person) design. I get sig interaction and main effect of person. However, the main effect of scenario is completrely blank in SPSS and JASP suggest F in very small 1.657 x10to-29. However,when I run a repeated measure with just the data for scenario I get  a very significant p-value p = .00000000000000015, etc, with an F-value of approx 39.

I am confused as to why I do not get any main effect in the 2 x 3 design, but get such a strong one for a repeated measures with just 3 levels of scenario.

I have check datasheet for inaccuracies, but cannot find any. The data points are being created from raw data and summed in to total scores using script in SPSS (which has been checked for correctness).

I am stumped and would appreciated any solutions or poentatial stats reason why this may be the case.

Thanks